Take a Ten Minutes Walk. What's wrong?
I am trying to solve this Codewars question (https://www.codewars.com/kata/54da539698b8a2ad76000228/train/javascript) but something doesn't work. I don't know what's wrong with my approach.Here is my code:
    function isValidWalk(walk) {
  if(walk.length > 10 || walk.length < 10){
    return false
  }else (walk.splice(0,5).join('') == walk.splice(5,5).map(x=>{
    if(x =='s'){
      return 'n'
    }else if(x=='n'){
      return 's'
    }
    else if(x=='w'){
      return'e'
    }
    else if(x=='e'){
      return 'w'
    }
  }).join(''))
    return true
  
}

Description of the question:
You live in the city of Cartesia where all roads are laid out in a perfect grid. You arrived ten minutes too early to an appointment, so you decided to take the opportunity to go for a short walk. The city provides its citizens with a Walk Generating App on their phones -- everytime you press the button it sends you an array of one-letter strings representing directions to walk (eg. ['n', 's', 'w', 'e']). You always walk only a single block for each letter (direction) and you know it takes you one minute to traverse one city block, so create a function that will return true if the walk the app gives you will take you exactly ten minutes (you don't want to be early or late!) and will, of course, return you to your starting point. Return false otherwise.
Note: you will always receive a valid array containing a random assortment of direction letters ('n', 's', 'e', or 'w' only). It will never give you an empty array (that's not a walk, that's standing still!).

if(walk.length > 10 || walk.length < 10) could be written as if (walk.length !== 10)

"but something doesn't work" is not an appropriate problem description. What is the expected behaviour what is the actual behaviour, what have you done to identify the problem?

Is the else (walk.splice(0,5).join('') == walk.splice(5,5).map(x=>{ supposed to be an else if?

@derpirscher I get this kind of error: should return false if walk does not bring you back to start
should return false: expected true to be false

Futhermore you are discarding many valid solutions as wrong: For instance a walk like n n w w s e e s s n is perfectly valid and will take you back to your starting point, but you won't accept it.

Count if the number of n and s match. Do the same for e and w.

The mistake is that you're assuming the second half of the walk is a direction-complemented copy of the first half of the walk.
For example, your program correctly thinks this walk is valid:
["n","n","e","e","w",  "s","s","w","w","e"]

But the program rejects these valid walks:
["n","n","e","e","w",  "e","s","s","w","w"]  // Some parts of the second half are reordered
["n","n","e","e","w",  "e","w","w","s","s"]  // Second half is a perfect reverse of the first half
["n","s", "e","w", "s","n", "w","e", "w","e"]  // Every pair takes you back to the origin
["n","n","s","s",  "w","w","w","e","e","e"]  // First 4 step take you back to origin, also last 6 steps

Without spoiling the answer, you will need a different approach in determining what a valid walk is.

"Without spoiling the answer"  If you don't want to post an answer you proably should put that in a comment ...

@derpirscher The question is "What's wrong?" Nobody asked for code or a fix. An answer describing the problem without a fix is IMO a perfectly fine answer.
